# Call of overloaded ‘pow(const double&, double)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, double

I am new to C++, here is my problem : I need this quantity :

```
h = pow(mesh.V()[i0],1.0/3);
```

but I get this error message whenever I compile the program :

```
    call of overloaded ‘pow(const double&, double)’ is ambiguous
```

And if I write

```
double V = mesh.V()[i0];
h = pow(V,1.0/3);
```

I get :

```
    call of overloaded ‘pow(double&, double)’ is ambiguous
```

Now I think I understand what const double& and double& refer to,but how can I convert the
const double& to a double?

Thanks!

Comment: use `std::pow()` instead. also make sure you include `<cmath>` instead of `math.h`.

Comment: What are the candidate overloads the compiler shows with the ambiguity message?

Comment: std::pow() worked like magic! thank you so much!

Comment: what does it do exactly?

Comment: @Farah.Yasmina: The qualification selects one of the overloads. I can imagine that you had something like `using namespace std;`, or you had another function called `pow` taking two doubles in your namespace.... or... that is why it is important to provide whole error messages. The compiler probably told you what overloads it was considering as ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I think I understand what const double& and double& refer to,but how can I convert the const double& to a double?

Beware that some compilers use that syntax in error messages to represent something different than what it means in code. The error messages are telling you what the type used as the argument to the function is, rather than what the function takes.

If you want to get `double` in the error message you just need to call a function that returns by value a `double`, but that is **not** what you want.

What you need is to find out why the call is ambiguous. Is the compiler giving you later in the error message what function signatures are considered? It should, and reading the different overloads that it is considering will help in finding out why it is ambiguous in this context.